# Better refactoring by moving if-statement inside the useEffect giving errors. - Nextjs/Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, use-effect, setstate

Code sandBox of the problem attached below

I want to move the if-Statement from outside to inside my useEffect (both located in the **useFetchMovieGenreResults** hook in the hooks folder) as I think that is better practice. However every time I move it inside I do not get my desired response in the console since setstate does not update immediately. I basically get null as my response. However when I have it outside the useEffect (the way it is default in my code sandbox), it gives me the correct response (an object) after a few renders)

**I am looking for a way to move my if-Statement inside my useEffect or remove the need for having an if-Statement all together. Any help?** I left my if-statement outside my useEffect in my codeSandbox just to demonstrate what a working copy looks like and what return it's supposed to give (in the console). Its the last render.

On a side note, any help on reducing the number of renders the application has until it gives you the correct output. Even with the if-statement outside the useEffect, It still takes 2 renders before my correct output is delivered. Not sure if this has anything to do with the associated fetch.

You can ignore the commented out lines in the codeSandbox as I am just using this to play around and learn a few things.

**What I have**

```
 useEffect(() => {
    setMymoviegenreinfo(
      mymoviegenreobjects,
      console.log("This is my infoooooo from the setstae", mymoviegenreinfo)
    );
  }, [mymoviegenreobjects]); 

if (mymoviegenreinfo?.genres?.length > 0) {
    var mappedvalues = Object.keys(mymoviegenreobjects).map(
      (e) => mymoviegenreobjects[e]
    );

    console.log("The latest testinggggggggggggggggggg", mappedvalues);

    const flatarrayofvalues = mappedvalues.flat();
    console.log("Finally flat", flatarrayofvalues);

    const filtteredarray = flatarrayofvalues.filter(
      (character) => character.name === genre
    );

    console.log("This is avangers two ID", filtteredarray[0].id);

    console.log("just a check", mymoviegenreinfo);
    console.log(
      "a check for lengthhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh",
      mymoviegenreinfo?.genres?.length
    );

    return mymoviegenreinfo;
  }
```

**But I want something like [note the if-statement]**

```
useEffect(() => {
        setMymoviegenreinfo(
          mymoviegenreobjects,
          console.log("This is my infoooooo from the setstae", mymoviegenreinfo)
if (mymoviegenreinfo?.genres?.length > 0) {t
        var mappedvalues = Object.keys(mymoviegenreobjects).map(
          (e) => mymoviegenreobjects[e]
        );
    
        console.log("The latest testinggggggggggggggggggg", mappedvalues);
    
        const flatarrayofvalues = mappedvalues.flat();
        console.log("Finally flat", flatarrayofvalues);
    
        const filtteredarray = flatarrayofvalues.filter(
          (character) => character.name === genre
        );
    
        console.log("This is avangers two ID", filtteredarray[0].id);
    
        console.log("just a check", mymoviegenreinfo);
        console.log(
          "a check for lengthhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh",
          mymoviegenreinfo?.genres?.length
        );
        );
      }, [mymoviegenreobjects]); 

    
    
        return mymoviegenreinfo;
      }
```

CodeSandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-wiles-2zxm38

Thanks!

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask] - note the [mre] must be in the question **as text**.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but couldn't you simply remove the `useEffect` block altogether? There's no need to store `mymoviegenreobjects` into state, just manipulate the response you get from `useFetchNavBarCatagories` and return it.